# How to fix problems with vector and T*

Tags: c++, pointers, sub-array, template-classes

I'm having a task, where I have to make a C++ implementation of a Java style ArrayList. But in a couple of areas I'm having some trouble.

The declaration of the .h and the main.cpp cannot be changed.

I have a template

```
template <class T>
class ArrayList
{
public:
    // ********* Applying rule of 5: constructors ******************
    // default constructor.
    ArrayList() //OK
    {
        mElements = new T[5];
        mReserved = 5;
        mSize = 0;
    }

    // copy constructor
    ArrayList(const ArrayList<T>& copyArray): mSize(copyArray.mSize), 
    mElements(new T[mSize])//OK
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
            mElements[i] = copyArray.mElements[i];
    }

    // move constructor
    ArrayList(ArrayList<T>&& moveArray): mSize(moveArray.mSize), 
    mElements(moveArray.mElements)//OK
    {
        moveArray.mSize = 0;
        moveArray.mElements = nullptr;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    ArrayList<T>& operator = (const ArrayList<T> &copyArrayOpt)//OK
    {
        if( &copyArrayOpt != this)
        {
            if (mSize != copyArrayOpt.mSize)
            {
                delete [] mElements;
                mSize = copyArrayOpt.mSize;
                mElements = new T[mSize];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
                mElements[i] = copyArrayOpt.mElements[i];

            return *this;
        }
    }

    // move assignment operator
    ArrayList<T>& operator = (ArrayList<T> && moveArrayOpt)//OK
    {
        if ( &moveArrayOpt != this)
        {
            delete [] mElements;
            mSize = moveArrayOpt.mSize;
            mElements = moveArrayOpt.mElements;

            moveArrayOpt.mSize = 0;
            moveArrayOpt.mElements = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~ArrayList()
    {
        delete [] mElements;
    }

    const T& operator[](int index) const;//OK
    T& operator[](int index);//OK
    int size() const;//OK
    int reserved() const;//OK
    bool isEmpty() const;//OK

    void add(const T& element);//OK
    void add(int index, const T& element);//OK
    void remove(int index);//OK
    void trimToSize();//OK

    void mergeSort(ArrayList<T>& mElements, int low, int high);
    void merge(ArrayList<T>& mElements, int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right);

    ArrayList<T> subArrayList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) const;
    T* toArray();

private:
    void extendStorage();//OK
    void wrongIndexInput();

    int mSize, mReserved;
    T* mElements;
};
```

The 2 functions causing trouble are
`ArrayList<T> subArrayList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` and
`T* toArray()`.

These I have implemented as follows:

```
template <class T>
ArrayList<T> ArrayList<T>::subArrayList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) const
{
    ArrayList<T> partialArray;
    int sizeP = toIndex - fromIndex;

    if (sizeP > partialArray.reserved())
    {
        partialArray.extendStorage();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeP); ++i)
    {
        partialArray[i] = partialArray;
    }
    return partialArray;
}
```

and

```
template <class T>
T* ArrayList<T>::toArray()
{
    std::vector<T*> array;

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = &mElements[i];
    }

    return *array.data();
}
```

In the main.cpp the two functions are called like this:

```
ArrayList<double> subArray = array.subArrayList(1,10);

std::cout << "Sub ArrayList have reserved space for " <<
             subArray.reserved() << " elements and stores "
          << subArray.size() << " elements. " << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < subArray.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << subArray[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\b\b  " << std::endl << std::endl;

// double* sArray = subArray.toArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    subArray.add(i + 1);
}

std::cout << "Basic array of sub array contains: " <<
             std::endl;
/*
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.size() - 7; ++i)
{
    std::cout << sArray[i] << ", ";
}
std::cout << "\b\b  " << std::endl << std::endl;
*/

std::cout << "Sub array with 7 elements added: " <<
             std::endl;
for (int i = 0 ; i < subArray.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << subArray[i] << ", ";
}
std::cout << "\b\b  " << std::endl << std::endl;
```

In the output from the subArrayList it says:

```
Sub ArrayList have reserved space for 10 elements and stores 0 elements.
```

And I have no clue why I can't get anything in the subarray.

When I run the other function, the program just crashes.

Comment: In `toArray()`: You copy the pointers to a `std::vector`, and then return the first vector element. The function body is basically equivalent to `return mElements[0];`. In `subArrayList()`: The line `partialArray[i] = partialArray;` seems strange.

Comment: Besides the above, I'm equally flummoxed by `if (sizeP > partialArray.reserved()) { partialArray.extendStorage(); }`. Unless `sizeP` is directly contributing to the expansion mechanics of `extendStorage` (and it isn't), if it wasn't big enough before, what possible guarantee is there it will be after?

Comment: Note that the `return` statement in the `ArrayList` copy assignment operator is at the wrong scope meaning execution can flow off the end of the function.  That's undefined behaviour.